# WooCommerce Auth REST API cURL error - SSL certificate problem self signed certificate

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to use the REST APIs provided by WooCommerce to read store data. In order to do that I need a [user key and secret](https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/). I'm trying to create it using the [Auth REST API provided by WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#rest-api-keys). I setup an endpoint in my backend service to capture the user key and secret that would be created by WooCommerce once the user provides their approval. The failure occurs in the final stage of the process where WooCommerce makes a call to the callback url which is my backend service that is setup to capture the user and secret keys which then I'll use to make calls to WooCommerce using their REST APIs.

[image]

The error I'm getting is
[image]

> Error : cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed
> certificate

I tried

1. Checking the certificate of the BE through online SSL cert validation tools. The certificate is not self signed.
2. Then made a mock service using Postman and made the same call and it succeeded. It didn't give the above mentioned error. That's how I narrowed it down and identified that there is something wrong with the callback URL service.
3. I tried using a trial WooCommerce setup in the Wordpress saas platform (the online version not setting it up locally) also I tried using a local Docker setup behind ngrok tunnel (it had a valid certificate non self signed), didnt make a difference.

Since its not a self signed certificate and WooCommerce is saying it's self signed, what might be the closest explanation for this error to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was an issue with the domain that was setup in the callback. The domain that I had in mind and the actual domain that was set in the callback were different and one had the proper certificates installed and the other did not (domain and sub domain, the certificate had not been configured for the sub domain). So when WooCommerce makes a call to the callback url with the auth values it rightfully gives the above mentioned error. So anyone facing this issue please check that first.